# RLO unicode character not working for windows1255

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, right-to-left, bidi, windows-1255

Is there another character like `\u202e` that results in the same functionality - a right to left override that is supported in windows1255 as well?

I've used `\u202e` so far but now, when sending a text to a system encoded with windows1255 the text replaces those with question marks - ???

How to have the same functionality in windows1255 encoding?

Comment: They [are there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255#Code_page_layout), 0xfd and 0xfe.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(0xfd)` will be interpeted in windows1255 as `\u202e` in Unicode?

Comment: @HansPassant 0xFD and oxFE are LRM and RLM characters, not RLO.